# change java text into pdf and then print it

Tags: java, pdf, printing

I am making a java desktop app using android studio(bcz don't have other tools available yet).
in my app, i have to add a print button which takes text from jtextarea convert it into pdf and then prints it.
I don't know how to do that. I have searched the internet but didn't find any helpful material.
I used printerjob but it prints the whole component as an image.
as given:

```
 public class Printer implements Printable {
    final Component comp;

    public Printer(Component comp){
        this.comp = comp;
    }

    @Override
    public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat format, int page_index) throws PrinterException {
        if (page_index > 0) {
            return Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;
        }

        // get the bounds of the component
        Dimension dim = comp.getSize();
        double cHeight = dim.getHeight();
        double cWidth = dim.getWidth();

        // get the bounds of the printable area
        double pHeight = format.getImageableHeight();
        double pWidth = format.getImageableWidth();

        double pXStart = format.getImageableX();
        double pYStart = format.getImageableY();

        double xRatio = pWidth / cWidth;
        double yRatio = pHeight / cHeight;


        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) graphics;
        g2.translate(pXStart, pYStart);
        //g2.scale(xRatio, yRatio);
        comp.print(g2);

        return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
    }
}

      public void printComponent() throws PrinterException {

        PrinterJob pjob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        PageFormat preformat = pjob.defaultPage();
        preformat.setOrientation(PageFormat.PORTRAIT);
        PageFormat postformat = pjob.pageDialog(preformat);
//If user does not hit cancel then print.
        if (preformat != postformat) {
            //Set print component
            pjob.setPrintable(new Printer(bluetoothText), postformat);
            if (pjob.printDialog()) {
                pjob.print();
            }
        }
```

if a text is more than one page it does not print that.
any help will be very appreciable.
thank you.

Comment: I would advise against using PDF in this case. With a java PrintJob you can do all, also paging etcetera. PDF adds an unnecessary layer.

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/printable.html - develop in a small test application.

Answer (score 0):

The support for PDF printing is plateform-dependent. If you just want to print text, you can use a `java.awt.font.LineBreakMeasurer` to split the text into lines and pages.

Comment: how to use this in my code. i am new to this don't know how it works